# LINQ and C# - Dealing with a potentially null parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I am relatively new to LINQ but looking for some "best practice" advice on how to deal with the following. I know there are many ways to deal with this, but looking to see how more experienced people would write the code.

My LINQ at present:

```
        var company = (from c in db.RPTINQUIRies
                      where c.CONCOM == concom && c.LOPER == engineer
                      orderby c.CREATION_DATE descending
                      select c);
```

Now the `ActionResult` parameter that is being passed in here (engineer) may or may not be empty. Where it is empty, I essentially want to remove the `&& C.LOPER == engineer` clause all together.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
where c.CONCOM == concom && (engineer == null || c.LOPER == engineer)
```

Alternatively, you could build up the query step by step:

```
var query = db.RPTINQUIRies.Where(c => c.CONCOM == concom);
if (engineer != null)
{
    query = query.Where(c => c.LOPER == engineer);
}
query = query.OrderByDescending(c => c.CREATION_DATE);
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of "best practice" I was after. I didn't know you could build up a query in such a way. Thanks Jon!